# Displaying a Text Adventure in a GUI

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to put my text adventure in a GUI,and  make it so there are no buttons just text and user input. This is the code for my GUI

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Window {

public static void createwindow() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game");

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Component textLabel = null;


    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    createwindow();  }

}
```

I have my text adventure in a separate class and was wondering if there was any easy way to display that in this GUI. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve, you could use a `DocumentListener` to monitor for changes to the text component or an `ActionListener` on a `JTextField`

Comment: See a [JTextArea](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) as a trivial "just text" output area.

Comment: Have a look at [How to Write a Document Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html), [How to Use Text Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) and [How to Write an Action Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Comment: I was just looking for a way to display it, I am using a scanner and a lot of if statements for the game part.

Comment: @MonkeyMan45rocks Then you're approaching the problem from the wrong direction, you shouldn't be mixing user input paradigms (console and GUI) as they tend to have different working requirements.  The user should be entering input and seeing output within your GUI OR from the console, not both

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Window {

public static void createwindow() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game");

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(600, 400);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

//    Component textLabel = null;
    JTextArea jta = new JTextArea();
    frame.add(jta);

//    frame.pack();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    createwindow();  }

}
```

In my understanding, you just want a `TextArea`.Is right?

Comment: And what about a `JScrollPane`?  How does the user recognise user input and add new text to it? Right now, this does't answer all the problems the OP needs answered based on the broadness of the question they are asking